# habilitar y deshabilitar boton submit con react-form-hook en React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy utilizando **react-hook-form** para mi formulario que consta de **dos input**, uno para escribir el titulo y el otro para la descripcion del producto.
cuando se hace el **submit** del formulario, la data de los input se guarda en una **variable de estado** llamada **Entradas** y se limpia el formulario. La idea es que mi formulario inicie con el **boton submit inhabilitado** y que solo se **habilite** cuando el formulario es valido.
De la forma que lo hice inicia inhabilitado pero nunca se habilita.

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  title: yup.string().required('campo obligatorio'),
  description: yup.string().required('campo obligatorio!'),
  // description: yup.number().positive().integer().required(),
});

const EjemploUno = () => {

  const{formState} = useForm();
  
  const {register,handleSubmit,formState: { errors },} = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
  
  const [Entradas, setEntradas] = useState([]);

  const onSubmit = (data, event) => {
      //event.preventDefault();
      console.log(data);
      setEntradas([
          ...Entradas, data
      ])

      // Limpia el formulario
      event.target.reset();      
    }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input
            name="title"
            type="text"
            {...register("title")}
            placeholder="titulo"
            className="form-control"
        />
        <small className="text-danger">{errors.title?.message}</small>

        <input
            name="description"
            type="text"
            {...register("description")}
            placeholder="description"
            className="form-control"
        />
        <small className="text-danger">{errors.description?.message}</small>

        <button 
          type="submit" 
          disabled={!formState.isDirty || !formState.isValid}>
            Enviar
        </button>
   
      </form>
      
      {
        Entradas.map((item, index) => 
            <div key={index}>{item.title} - {item.description}</div>
        )
      }
     
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default EjemploUno;
```